# Make HTML Canvas generate PDF-ready Line art?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, html5-canvas, svg.js

I have an HTML/JavaScript program that uses the HTML5 canvas to generate a pretty graph:

[image]

I want to include this graph in a book that I'm producing with LaTeX. Unfortunately, when I print this page to PDF, I get a bitmap—presumably because canvas is a bitmap.

I just checked and apparently if I had developed this with SVG instead of with HTML5 canvas I would be good to go. But I didn't. So is there any way to generate line art from HTML5 Canvas, or should I just bite the bullet and re-implement this as SVG?

(I used canvas instead of svg because I thought that Canvas was preferred, more-modern, and more efficient. Was I mistaken?)

EDIT: Here is my JavaScript for drawing each arrow. I believe that I can readily port this to SVG using [svg.js](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/)

```
    /* Draw a Piece at its rotation at the position row,col */
    drawRotatedPiece(p) {
        let x = this.x(p.col);
        let y = this.y(p.row);
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.translate( x, y);
        this.ctx.fillStyle='white';
        this.ctx.fillRect( -this.radius, -this.radius, this.radius*2, this.radius*2 );
        this.ctx.rotate( p.angle * Math.PI / 180);
        this.ctx.moveTo( 0, -this.radius );
        this.ctx.lineTo( -this.radius, 0 );
        this.ctx.lineTo( +this.radius, 0 );
        this.ctx.closePath( );
        this.ctx.fillStyle='black';
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.fillRect( -this.radius/2.0, 0, this.radius, this.radius*2/3.0 );
        this.ctx.restore();

    }
```

Comment: Pixels are great when the output size is fixed. Start talking DPIs and output size like one does when concerned with print and you start needing images of different sizes to fill a given area. Think about your choice of LaTeX - you're not trying to store images of the pages in a book, you're trying to store the data used to render the images of the text. You should do the same thing with the images - store their definition, not their implementation. Yes, just redraw with SVG.

Comment: You will somehow have to reproduce the draw calls of the HTML5 canvas API, such as by writing a wrapper class that wraps an HTML5 canvas and translates those calls into calls that write SVG or PDF commands.  However, this is not exactly easy to do, depending on how you're using the HTML5 canvas API.  You should edit your question to include code that shows how you generated the graphic using the HTML5 canvas API.

Comment: In any case, your graphic looks simple enough -- just a bunch of stroked and filled paths -- that my note on the [Essentials of SVG](https://peteroupc.github.io/svg.html) may help you translate the graphic to SVG.

Comment: No you don’t need svg.js. Your canvas code is quite simple. It wouldn’t be too much hassle to manually port it to svg. Just bite that bullet. And if you’re not familiar with svg, well this is the perfect chance to learn something new. Basically you just need to learn the ["d" attribute of path element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

Comment: Last I checked pdf didn't support svg out of the box either. Their vector graphics were not compatible with svg, so instead of converting this to svg, rather learn their vector format (I believe using their GUI might be easier though).

Comment: @Kaiido - learn whose vector format?  I am going to just ask my web power to print to PDF....

Comment: @hackape - that's for the encouragement!

Comment: PDF's vector format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is code that generates SVG that reproduces the rotated piece you have given in your question.  The method is `drawRotatedPiece(x, y, radius, angle)`.

```
// Generate a SVG path command
function xycmd(cmd,x,y){
 return cmd+ x + " " + y;
}

function rectpathxy(x,y,w,h){
   return xycmd("M", x, y) +
          xycmd("L", x+w, y) +
          xycmd("L", x+w, y+h) +
          xycmd("L", x, y+h) +
          "Z";
}

function drawRotatedPiece(x, y, radius, angle){
  trans=[];
  svg="";
  svg+="<path style='stroke:red;fill:white'";
  svg+=" transform='translate("+x+","+y+")'";
  svg+=" d='";
  svg+=rectpathxy(-radius, -radius, radius*2, radius*2);
  svg+="'/>";
  svg+="<path style='stroke:none;fill:black'";
  svg+=" transform='translate("+x+","+y+") rotate("+angle+")'";
  svg+=" d='";
  var w=radius;
  var h=radius*2/3.0;
  svg+= xycmd("M", 0, -radius) +
        xycmd("L", -radius, 0) +
        xycmd("L", +radius, 0) +
        "Z" +
        xycmd("M", x,     y) +
        xycmd("L", x+w,   y) +
        xycmd("L", x+w, y+h) +
        xycmd("L", x,   y+h) +
        "Z";
  svg+="'/>";
  return svg;
}
```

In case you need to generate any other graphics in SVG format (especially simple graphics like yours that are just a bunch of stroked and filled paths), my note on the [Essentials of SVG](https://peteroupc.github.io/svg.html) may help you translate those graphics to SVG.

Comment: (did you know svg has a transform attribute?)

Comment: @Kaiido: Yes but I wasn't very familiar with it in detail.  I will see if I can incorporate that attribute.

Comment: Woah! That is great. But we want to use `transform`....

Comment: This answer (the edited version) already generates that attribute.

Comment: So it does! I will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: @PeterO. — Thank you so much for your help in this. I have taken what you have written and cleaned it up and will post it, but I will accept your solution so you get the credit. I believe your style of not putting `;` at the end of each line is problematic, but otherwise your code is clean and easy to follow. However, I have simplified the arrow to a single path. I've also made the `translate` and the `rotate` different transforms on different elements so that the knowledge of drawing is separated from where the drawing takes place. I will post the complete working example on GitHub shortly.

Comment: Follow-up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485761/use-svg-animatetransform-to-rotate-a-path-within-a-translated-svg-within-a-svg